# Does DataFrameMapper guarantees feature vector alignment?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

My project involves establishing a relation between a title and some mesures.

I'm relying on pandas and sklearn for the work and getting the hang out of sklearn-pandas because I've found it's DataFrameMapper convenient to handle the feature extraction step instead of chaining lots of feature unions.

In a nutshell this is something like:

```
dfm = DataFrameMapper([
    ('title', CountVectorizer()),
    (['width', 'height', 'length', 'weight'], StandardScaler()),
])
```

Then I want to use it on a pipeline like this:

```
p = make_pipeline(dfm, LinearRegression())
```

This kinds of looks like it should work. But I'm getting that it doesn't keep the "alignment" of my features.

When I try to train this simple model like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")  # a couple hundred thousands of records.
train_sample = data[:100000]  # arbitrary sample.
test_sample = data[100000:]  # arbitrary test.
p.fit(train_sample, train_sample['target'])
p.predict(test_sample)
```

It fails with:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,7) and (18,) not aligned: 7 (dim 1) != 18 (dim 0)
```

I get that this is due to the train sample being "bigger" than the test sample so the CountVectorizer vocabulary contains fewer features. But intuitively I'd hope that the pipeline (and the DataFrameMapper inside it)  would fill missing values that might appear.

At this point I don't know if this due to me using the DFM wrong. Or if I'm missing some silly configuration step.

May anyone point me my error here?

Comment: shouldn't it be: `p.fit(train_sample.drop('target', axis=1), train_sample['target'])` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited the question.

Comment: Actually, dropping the target column makes no difference... Gonna do a new edit.

Comment: Why do you repeat the `width` and `height` in the selector `['width', 'height', 'width', 'weight']`? Do you get the same error without using the DFM, i.e. using `FeatureUnion`? Can you provide the full traceback?